# Restructuring csv data with read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv

i'm new in R and stackoverflow, i need your help with a restructure of a csv data in R, i'm reading a file where each row represents variable n points of a graphic x,y with the next structure:

```
code  x   y   x   y  x  y  x  y
1     1   0   2   2  3  3  4  5   // 1rst graphic with 4 points
2     1   1   2   3               // 2nd graphic with only 2 points
3     0   2   3   5  5  12 10 23  // 3rd graphic with 4 points
```

the output cvs estructure that I need structure like this:

```
code x  y
 1   1  0
 1   2  2
 1   3  3
 1   4  5
 2   1  1
 2   2  3
 3   0  2
 3   3  5
 3   5  12
 3  10  23
```

Is this possible with only use read.csv and how?
appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: not directly with `read.csv`, but yes, very doable.  Use `readLines` to read in your data, then please post a reproducible example. Yoou can use    `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here:  http://bit.ly/SORepro   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ricardo pointed out in a comment, this is not directly doable with `read.csv`. Instead, you can read the data in, and then use `reshape` to get your output. I've added a few extra steps to drop rows with `NA` values and so on, but this is not entirely necessary.

The data, as you have presented it. You mention it is a CSV, so you'll probably be using `read.csv` instead of `read.table`.

```
out <- read.table(text = "code  x   y   x   y  x  y  x  y
1     1   0   2   2  3  3  4  5   // 1rst graphic with 4 points
2     1   1   2   3               // 2nd graphic with only 2 points
3     0   2   3   5  5  12 10 23  // 3rd graphic with 4 points", 
                  fill = TRUE, comment.char = "/", header = TRUE)
```

Change the names of the first "x" and "y" pair so that they have a ".0" appended to them.

```
names(out)[2:3] <- c("x.0", "y.0")
out
#   code x.0 y.0 x.1 y.1 x.2 y.2 x.3 y.3
# 1    1   1   0   2   2   3   3   4   5
# 2    2   1   1   2   3  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 3    3   0   2   3   5   5  12  10  23
```

Use `reshape` to get your desired data form.

```
outL <- reshape(out, direction = "long", idvar="code", varying = 2:ncol(out))
outL <- outL[order(outL$code), ]
outL[complete.cases(outL), -2]
#     code  x  y
# 1.0    1  1  0
# 1.1    1  2  2
# 1.2    1  3  3
# 1.3    1  4  5
# 2.0    2  1  1
# 2.1    2  2  3
# 3.0    3  0  2
# 3.1    3  3  5
# 3.2    3  5 12
# 3.3    3 10 23
```

Comment: Really nice, it works perfect! I never thought to change the names of the first "x" and "y" pair. Thanks a lot for your help!